# How to use the [musicians] tag?

Tags: discussion

The current excerpt of [musicians](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/musicians) is:

> For questions regarding specific musicians or musicians as a whole

Do we really want to use this tag for *both* cases, questions about specific musicians and questions about musicians in general?

Currently it’s used by 2 questions about specific musicians:

- [How did Jaco Pastorius get nicknamed 'Jaco'?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-did-jaco-pastorius-get-nicknamed-jaco)
- [What happened to Poe?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/164/what-happened-to-poe)

And by 3 questions about musicians in general:

- [Why do so many musicians use stage names instead of their real names?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-do-so-many-musicians-use-stage-names-instead-of-their-real-names)
- [Most longevity on the pop charts](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/61/most-longevity-on-the-pop-charts)
- [Who is the artist of a song?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/104/who-is-the-artist-of-a-song)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I don't see much use for a tag as broad as [musicians](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/musicians).  I can't imagine a music fan who would like to filter out questions about albums if those questions involve the musicians who made them, or vice versa.  Even if it's used for musicians in general I just don't see how it creates meaningful categorization separate from other tags.  If a tag has no actual use as a category, it's a bad tag and should be removed.

Answer (score -1):

I think we should use this tag only for questions about musicians in general.

For questions about specific musicians, tags about the involved musicians should be added.

Why?

- Following the [musicians](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/musicians) tag doesn’t make much sense if there are all these questions about specific musicians (that you might not even know) included. There can be no expert in *all* specific musicians.
- A tag about a specific musician would include questions about this musician and questions about the works of this musician, both of which are related fields: an expert in one of these areas is likely also an expert (or versed) in the other one; i.e., a fan often knows both, the musician and the music, and so it makes sense to follow this tag.
- The same is currently the case for [genre](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genre), which should not be used for questions about specific genres.

So I think the excerpt should be (wording improvements welcome!):

> For general questions about musicians. Do not use for questions about specific musicians.

If we agree, I think [album](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/album), [bands](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bands), [soundtrack](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soundtrack), and [cover](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cover) should be handled in the same way.