# Can we burninate the tag [track]?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, retagging

The tag [track](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/track) has no excerpt or wiki, and there are four questions tagged with it:

- [Why are bonus tracks so common in japanese versions?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/150/3955)
- [What is the genre of "Kiss me (IMSA remix)"?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/3634/3955)
- [Original of song used frequently as background for "quiet storm"](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/4286/3955)
- [the piano background of this video](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/5957/3955)

Since tracks are considered synonymous with songs<sup>[1]</sup> [for the purpose of tagging](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/a/358/3955), this tag is certainly too broad to be of good use, much like the tag [musicians](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/musicians) [which was burninated](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/a/170/3955).

Is it okay to go ahead and retag these questions to burninate the tag [track](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/track)?

It might be worth mentioning that an example of a related tag with decent scope is [hidden-track](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hidden-track): four questions are tagged with it and it has some rudimentary [usage guidance](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tags/hidden-track/info).

---

<sup>[1]: On that note, there is also this interesting question on Main: [Is every piece of music a "track"?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/120/3955)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag [track](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/track) has now been burninated.